# authorized_key file is missing - AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, authorized-keys

I have been using AWS instance for more than a month now. But all of a sudden I could not login to my AWS using SSH. I said Permission denied (public key). Then I found something has to be appended to the authorized_keys , I went searching for the file in `~.ssh/` folder . But it was missing. I am new to this. Somebody help me.

Comment: You need to create the `.ssh` directory and add the `authorized_key` file.

Comment: This is not AWS-specific, it's how public-key authorization works with  any SSH server.

Comment: I am not able to create or edit any files since I have lost authentication. So now how do it create a new file?

Comment: Doesn't AWS provide a way to get into the root account? From there you should be able to edit files for other users.

Comment: Yes. Only on that hope I have posted this question. Can you please  share a best way to do so.

Comment: @Venky Confused, how could you search for the ssh folder if you are locked out? It's not ~.ssh btw, it is cd ~/.ssh.